# How can I have a button in Kivy that when pressed, creates a label?

Tags: python, button, kivy

I would like to make a button so that when it is pressed, a label appears.

Comment: This is covered in the documentation: https://kivy.org/docs/guide/widgets.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply define a function that creates a label and assign it to the button's on_press event. Consider the following code:

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import Gridlayout
from kivy.app import App

layout = Gridlayout(cols = 1)
mybtn = Button(on_press = myfunction)
layout.add_widget(mybtn)

def myfunction():
    mylabel = Label(text = "This is a label")
    layout.add_widget(mylabel)

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return mylayout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp().run()
```

All of this, however, is covered in the kivy documentation, which is very comprehensive and has very good examples. Before you do anything, you should get the hang of it by reading it and trying out the examples by yourself.